# Regex Match URL Without Query String

Tags: regex

I need to match https://example.com/ exactly but ignore any query strings so:

https://example.com/something should not match but https://example.com/?abc should match.

I've tried using `https:\/\/www\.example\.com\/[^?]*` but that doesn't seem to work and I'm struggling to find other suitable examples.

Apologies if this has been answered before, I've spent the last half an hour searching the site...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^https:\/\/example\.com(\/?\?.*)?$` will match

```
https://example.com/?abc
https://example.com?abc
https://example.com
```

but ignore

```
    https://example.com/something
```

Is that what you're looking for? Demo at https://regex101.com/r/B22n1p/1

Comment: Appreciate you handling URLs that don't end in a trailing slash there too, thank you!

Comment: Actually I've just been testing this and realised that it doesn't match `https://example.com/` on its own?

Comment: "ignore any query strings" is confusing. I've adapted my answer. My advice is next time to list clearly the strings you want to match and strings you want to not match with your regex.

Comment: Why do not include your own solution in the answer? `^https:\/\/example\.com(\/?\?.*)?$`

Comment: Bug. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that `?` is an "optional quantifier".

I managed to get the desired with this expression.

```
(https:\/\/((www\.)|())example\.com)\/(([\?].*)|$)
```

Try it [here](https://regexr.com/6plec) for yourself.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm not sure what you mean about `?` being an optional qualifier? Alex beat you to it and their solution is a little bit easier to read so I've accepted their answer.

Comment: Actually I found an issue with their answer, I've accepted yours instead now 